# OnTouchEvent() program exits when touch screen

Tags: android

i have this program that basically when you touch the screen need to stop the "person"
the person moving only from left to right.

my person class

```
package com.example.pedestriancrossing2;
```

public class Person {

```
private float x,y;
private int height,width;
private int screenWidth;
private int destination;
private boolean needStop;
private float tempX;
public Person (float x, float y, int height, int width, int screenW)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.screenWidth = screenW;
    this.destination = -1;

}
public float left()
{
    return x-width;
}
public float right()
{
    return x+width;
}
public float Top()
{
    return y-height;
}
public float Bottom()
{
    return y+height;
}

public void setDestination (int destination)
{
    this.destination = destination;
}
public void movePerson ()
{

    if(right()>=screenWidth)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    if(destination == -1)
        x++;



}
```

}

and my main activity>>

```
package com.example.pedestriancrossing2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Person person;
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Point p = new Point();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
    int screenWidth = p.x;
    int screenHeigh = p.y;
    Car car = new Car( screenWidth/2 , screenHeigh/2 , 15 , screenHeigh);
    Person person = new Person( 0 , screenHeigh/2 , 10 , 20 , screenWidth);
    CarView carview = new CarView(this, car);
    PersonView personview = new PersonView(this, person);
    GameView gameview = new GameView(this);
    gameview.setViews(carview, personview);
    setContentView(gameview);
    CarMover moveCar = new CarMover(car,gameview);
    PersonMover movePerson = new PersonMover(person, gameview);

    person.setDestination(-1);
    moveCar.start();
    movePerson.start();
    /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/

    /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }*/
}
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (person != null) return false;
    int destination = event.getAction();
    if(destination == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        person.setDestination(1);
    }
    if(destination == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        person.setDestination(-1);
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/*@Override*/
/*public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int isTouched;
    isTouched = event.getAction();
    if(isTouched == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        person.setNeedStop(true);
    }
    if(isTouched == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        person.setNeedStop(false);
    }

    return true;


}*/
```

}

Logcat:

```
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.pedestriancrossing2.MainActivity.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:57)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2461)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:260)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-30 13:57:45.092: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when i am executing the program everything works fine but when i touch the screen the program suddenly crash.
i am using nexus S as an emulator.

Comment: Ok, add logcat so we can help you.

Comment: here is a download link for a log file:
http://www.speedyshare.com/b9rPM/log.txt
sorry i couldnt add it here..

Comment: Added for you, you should only add the logcat which appeared when the application crash not everything!

Comment: Anyway what is line 57 of MainActivity?

Comment: here is line 57:
person.setDestination(1);
and here i uploaded a new log only with the logs from the start of the crash:
http://www.speedyshare.com/732xt/log.txt

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fix your problem, you should make sure `person` refer to an instance of your class.

Example

```
person = new Person();
```

in `onCreate`. Person is an example, change it with your class.

You cannot use `person` until you assing an instance to it.

---

Change onTouchEvent to it

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (person != null) return false;
    int destination = event.getAction();
    if(destination == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        person.setDestination(1);
    }
    if(destination == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        person.setDestination(-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Maybe in some strange way `onTouchEvent` is called before `person` gets the instance.

Comment: i already did it and it still doesn't work.
Person person = new Person( 0 , screenHeigh/2 , 10 , 20 , screenWidth);

is it what you ment?

Comment: Yes, where you added it?

Comment: And make sure it happens before onTouchEvent, or avoid it temporally using `if (person == null) return false;`

Comment: i can add all the code of person and myactivity classes if it can help

Comment: I can't see anything wrong for now, i edited my answer

Comment: Anyway, maybe your logcat was out-dated? Maybe you changed the code and now it refer to a different line can you reproduce again the crash and post a new logcat more recent?

Comment: i have few errors in the error log of eclipse, maybe one of them is the problem. take a look:
http://postimg.org/image/qemgakmq5/

Comment: Remeber you should read LogCat messages to understand what happens in Android

Comment: i changed the code as u recommended me. and it still crashes.
here is the log:
http://www.speedyshare.com/6ysAn/lognew.txt

Comment: line 58 of MainActivity? MainActivity.java:58

Comment: The same line:
person.setDestination(1);

Comment: Impossible, have you added if (person != null) check?

Comment: yes. i also tried executing the program when i say from the start that 
person.setDestination(1); without the onTouchEvent. everything works fine with that. the problem remains when i click on the screen

Comment: still no idea? cuz i am stuck

Comment: If (person == null) return false; my mistake sorry